# frequency count of words in text column in pandas dataframe and store it in other column

Tags: python, pandas, text-processing

1. DataFrame view

[image]

I have a Pandas DataFrame with reviews column as in the image above.
I want to get the count of each word in every row of the product['review'] column and store it into another column, namely products['word_count']. The code I trying is as below:

```
products['word_count'] = products['review'].apply(lambda x : nltk.FreqDist)
```

However, instead of word count I am getting a <class 'nltk.probability.FreqDist'> object in the column

Comment: Your getting exactly what your asking your code to do. Your passing a FreqDist class into the column. The `<class .......>` cant be printed out onto the screen automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you are applying lambda incorrectly, you should give the parameter as "x" as well:

```
# lambda x : nltk.FreqDist
lambda x : nltk.FreqDist(x)
```

But it will not solve your problem either.

From my perspective you may need two different solutions:

**Solution 1**: Total count of words as integer

```
products['word_count'] = products['review'].apply(lambda x : len(x.split(" ")))
```

**Solution 2**: The frequency distrubution as dictionary

```
products['word_count'] = products['review'].apply(lambda x : nltk.FreqDist(nltk.word_tokenize(x)))
```